# How do I translate gps sports data into a representative plane

Tags: qgis, postgis, gps, coordinate-system

I'm hoping to use qgis and postgis for a project but I'm unsure of, how to not only frame the question but accomplish the task.

If I have gps data from 1 runner on an oval track but who has run on ovals at multiple locations how do I transform/translate/format the gps data so that I can represent the traces accurately on a "representative" oval using qgis and storing the data in postgis ?

The representative oval doesn't necessarily have to exist in the real world (or should I pick an oval track and translate or map the other locations to it) so for example I could see the traces from a run in New York and LA on the same generic oval be that a real location or not

Comment: What do you want to display? The speed?

Comment: I'd like to use the Time Manager plugin for qgis to create animation of the different races but superimpose them onto 1 representative oval track so the runner could compare their performance visually enough though the races were in different parts of the world

Comment: Couldn't this be done more effectively outside of GIS? For instance: 1) extract the time per lap for each oval 2) animate the different times on a "standard oval" with something like D3.js. I don't see the necessity of using geospatial data when your first step is to discard the geospatial information.

Comment: I want to keep the geo data so that for example you could see that in New York the runner ended up running in the outside lanes for longer because competitors forced them out not just they finished later.  If you look at this image I found online and then assume I wanted to plot/overlay the same data from 2 different ovals  [link](http://bit-player.org/2015/the-long-run)  Is there a standard or most used way of transforming data from multiple locations to 1 ? **Should I pick a "home" track and transform the data from the other locations so its as if they were occurred on the home track?**

Comment: How about creating a centroid for your oval run data, then translate each track data using the centroid as origin to a common destination for all tracks centroids? Of course, the accuracy of this method will depend on the tracked data line shape.

Comment: Hi @Techie_Gus would you be able to outline the steps to do that in qgis?

Comment: @Michael I couldn't do that out of the back of my head without trying it out first and I don't have a PC available right now to test it. But creating the centroid of a polygon is fairly easy. The command is somewhere in the vector menu. So first step is to convert your line into a polygon. Perhaps some of the QGISers could chime in with a step by step.